# Can't install RMagick on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion, rmagick

I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm running Mac OS 10.7 (Mountain Lion), and I'm trying to install the RMagick gem so I can use it in my Rails 3 app. I already installed imagemagick with homebrew, and that seemed to finish successfully. I also installed the XQuartz package. When I add 'rmagick' to my gemfile and run bundle install, I get this error:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /Users/Andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/Andrew/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Process finished with exit code 5
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by following these steps. Arrggh!

1. Install XCode 4.4
2. Install command line tools (from the preferences in Xcode)
3. Install XQuartz
4. Install ImageMagic (brew install —vd imagemagick)
5. sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
6. mdfind MagickWand.h (to get the path to the MagickWand.h file)
7. C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick

Comment: I also needed to tell RVM that I was using the global gemset before installing the rmagick gem. The first time I installed it, it installed into the wrong gemset, and wasn't seen by the app